# Pandas bar plot edge to dash

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have a bar plot and I can successfully turn the fill color to transparent.  Now I'd like to change the edge to a dashed line, instead of a solid.

`df.plot(kind='barh', x='state', y='population', color=[1,0,0,0], edgecolor='blue', width=0.5)`

I've tried `edgestyle`, I've tried `style='-'` and `'--'`.

Is dash-ing only available for line plots?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`df.plot(kind='barh', x='state', y='population', color=[1,0,0,0], edgecolor='blue', width=0.5, linestyle="--")`